# Android's lint does not warn if the wrong LayoutInflator.inflate method is used

Tags: android, user-interface, lint

If you use:
`LayoutInflator.inflate(resource, parent)` instead of `LayoutInflator.inflate(resource, parent, false)`

you will most likely run into problems at runtime.

I'd like to see a lint warning for this or understand why this may not be a problem in all cases.

Comment: What kind of problems you're getting at runtime?

Comment: At runtime you will receive an exception.

Comment: Which exception? Can you post the message from it?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to see a lint warning for this

This is not an issue tracker.

> why this may not be a problem in all cases

The two-parameter `inflate()` is fine if your objective is to add the inflated layout as a tree of children to the designated parent. In some cases, this is what you want. In other cases, it is not. I will readily agree that for most developers and most use cases, the three-parameter-with-`false` `inflate()` is the right answer (e.g., `ListAdapter`, `RecyclerView.Adapter`).

Comment: Just small addition for reading https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/